# %spark2.r on hdp sandbox/zeppelin doesn't work

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-zeppelin, sparkr, ambari

We are running zeppelin on a hdp sandbox managed with ambari, pyspark, sql and scala is working but %spark2.r is not. Any ideas please? - I swear I looked everywhere.

I tried checkin the SPARK_HOME = /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/ but idk if that is the correct folder - how can I check? I installed Rstudio on the sandbox and it is working fine and when I try to run R code in the shell in the box it works as well. R is installed I am sure.

```
%spark2.r
foo <- TRUE
print(foo)
bare <- c(1, 2.5, 4)
print(bare)
double <- 15.0
print(double)

org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: sparkr is not responding 
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.
  Natural language support but running in an English locale
R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.
Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
> #
> # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
> # or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
> # distributed with this work for additional information
> # regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
> # to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
> # "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
> # with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
> #
> #     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
> #
> # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
> # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
> # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
> # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
> # limitations under the License.
> #
> 
> args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
> 
> hashCode <- as.integer(args[1])
> port <- as.integer(args[2])
> libPath <- args[3]
> version <- as.integer(args[4])
> rm(args)
> 
> print(paste("Port ", toString(port)))
[1] "Port  42159"
> print(paste("LibPath ", libPath))
[1] "LibPath  /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client//R/lib"
> 
> .libPaths(c(file.path(libPath), .libPaths()))
> library(SparkR)
Attaching package: ‘SparkR’
The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
    cov, filter, lag, na.omit, predict, sd, var, window
The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
    as.data.frame, colnames, colnames<-, drop, endsWith, intersect,
    rank, rbind, sample, startsWith, subset, summary, transform, union
> 
> 
> SparkR:::connectBackend("localhost", port, 6000)
A connection with                               
description "->localhost:42159"
class       "sockconn"         
mode        "wb"               
text        "binary"           
opened      "opened"           
can read    "yes"              
can write   "yes"              
> 
> # scStartTime is needed by R/pkg/R/sparkR.R
> assign(".scStartTime", as.integer(Sys.time()), envir = SparkR:::.sparkREnv)
> 
> # getZeppelinR
> .zeppelinR = SparkR:::callJStatic("org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinR", "getZeppelinR", hashCode)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinR.waitForRScriptInitialized(ZeppelinR.java:285)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinR.request(ZeppelinR.java:227)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinR.eval(ZeppelinR.java:176)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinR.open(ZeppelinR.java:165)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkRInterpreter.open(SparkRInterpreter.java:90)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:493)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did you update `zeppelin-env.sh` with `SPARK_HOME`?

Comment: no, Im not sure how to go about that

Comment: Have you check the interpreter log ?

Comment: @Morte https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.5.6-incubating/interpreter/spark.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks karma4917 for pointing me to the right direction - https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/interpreter/r.html#overview

following this link stepbystep solved the error